# Inserting and getting the position in a Linked List class using python

Tags: python, list, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I am new to Data Structure and algorithms. I'm a self-taught Python programmer. I am doing a course on it and I wanted to make a linked list, get a specific position in the linked list, insert, and delete an element in the list.
So I wrote my code, and to me, it seems fine. It's not giving me any errors, but it's not executing as well.

This is the code that I wrote,

```
class Element(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
        
class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.head = head
        
    def append(self, new_element):
        current = self.head
        if self.head:
            while current.next:
                current = current.next
            current.next = new_element
        else:
            self.head = new_element
            
    def get_position(self, position):
        """Get an element from a particular position.
        Assume the first position is "1".
        Return "None" if position is not in the list."""
        
        current = self.head
        if self.head:
            while current.next:
                if current == position:
                    return current
                else:
                    continue
        
        else:
            return None
    
    def insert(self, new_element, position):
        """Insert a new node at the given position.
        Assume the first position is "1".
        Inserting at position 3 means between
        the 2nd and 3rd elements."""
        
        current = self.head
        if self.head:
            while current.next:
                if current.next == position:
                    current.next = new_element
                    break
                else:
                    continue
        else:
            self.head = new_element
```

**The error is in get position function and insert function**

can anyone tell me what is it that I'm doing wrong?
Is there an issue with the loop or something?
Please help me, I'll be grateful!! Thanks.

Comment: *"The error is in..."*: please provide error message and indicate in which line.

Comment: I'm not getting an error message, but the code is not executing either. I'm using Jupyter Notebook, and it just keeps loading as I start to execute the given functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some issues in `get_position`:

- `current == position` is not the condition you need to verify.  `position` is a number and `current` is an Element, so they don't really compare. You need to verify whether the `position` is 1 or 2, ... depending on how far you are in your list.
- The loop never advances `current` to the next node. So this represents an infinite loop.
- The `while` condition should not check `current.next`, but `current`. Otherwise you will never do a check for the last node in the list.

Here is your code corrected:

```
def get_position(self, position):
    if position < 1:  # Just in case the position is too small
        return
    current = self.head
    while current and position > 1:
        position -= 1
        current = current.next
    return current
```

So the loop ends whenever position gets to be decreased to 1, or there is no more node. In the latter case the return value will be `None`.

Although your question is about the `get_position` function, your `insert` also has the same problems. On top of that it also treats the `head` case wrong. It should also change the `head` when the provided position is 1.

The `insert` method can in fact make use of the above function to find the node that should precede the node to be inserted:

```
def insert(self, new_element, position):
    if position == 1:
        new_element.next = self.head
        self.head = new_element
    else:
        before = self.get_position(position-1)
        if before is None:
            raise ValueError("invalid position")
        new_element.next = before.next
        before.next = new_element
```

Comment: This works, Thank you so much. I have some questions though... first, the linked list funct that I created works fine with while loop condition 'current.next', why can't I use the same condition to loop through the same linked list, rather then using 'current and position>1'? because I have stated the current variable as head. So can I just write a condition for position 1 and then iterate through next positions with the same while loop I wrote? Thank you so much for the help, really appreciated !!

Comment: The loop with `current.next` is intended to find the last node in a list. If in `append` we would use `current` as condition, you'd be left with `None` after the loop and still not know what the last node is. For the other two methods the goal is different as you have a `position` to take into account, which you don't deal with in `append`. Sure there is a way to also have a loop with `current.next`, but then you need to have a special case for when you need the first node. There are often several ways to come to the same result.

Comment: That clears the doubt!! Thank you so much for this, I'm grateful!